How many photons are received per bit transmitted from Voyager 1?
As of 2024, according to https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/ , Voyager 1 is around one light·day away from Earth and still in radio contact. When Voyager 1 sends messages to Earth, roughly how many photons are (1) transmitted and (2) received per bit?

There is now a long thread on HackerNews about this post: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=40561872

Does it make sense to speak of photons when it comes to radio waves?

@PeterMortensen as much as it does at other wavelengths. And judging by Jos's answer we're getting into the realm where shot noise (the "lumpiness" in the arrival rate of signal photons, considered as a Poisson process) starts to become a factor, so we probably should speak about them.

For an exact calculation we need to address a few choices: (you can change them, the answer will not be tremendously affected)

What is the receiver? Let's assume a 70 m dish, like this one [CDSCC] in the Deep Space Network.
[Voyager 1] can transmit at $2.3 {\rm GHz}$ or $8.4 {\rm GHz}$. Let's assume $8.4 {\rm GHz}$, for better beam forming (but probably it can only use the lowest frequency at the highest power, so this could be too optimistic).
Does "received" mean all photons hitting the antenna dish, or only those entering the electronic circuit of the first LNA? A similar question can be asked for the transmitter in the space craft. We'll ignore this here since losses related to illuminators or Cassegrain construction will not even be one order of magnitude, insignificant compared with the rest.

Answers:
A) Voyager sends $160$ bits/second with $23{\rm W}$. Using $8.3 {\rm GHz}$ this is $4 \cdot 10^{24}$ photons per second, or $2.6 \cdot 10^{22}$ per bit, because for frequency $f$ the energy per photon is only
$$E_\phi=\hbar\, \omega=2\pi\hbar f=5.5\cdot10^{-24}{\rm J} \ \ 
\text{or} \ \ 5.5 \ \text{yJ (yoctojoule)}.$$
B) The beam forming by Voyager's $d=3.7{\rm m}$  dish will direct them predominantly to Earth, with $(\pi d/\lambda)^2$ antenna gain, but still, at the current  distance of $R=23.5$ billion kilometers, this only results in $3.4\cdot10^{-22}$  Watt per square meter reaching Earth, so a receiver with a $D=70{\rm m}$ dish will collect only $1.3$ attowatt ($1.3\cdot 10^{-18}{\rm W}$), summarized by:
$$
  P_{\rm received} = P_{\rm transmit}\ \Big(\frac{\pi d}{\lambda}\Big)^2 \ \frac1{4\pi R^2}\ \frac{\pi D^2}4
$$
Dividing by $E_\phi$ we see that this power then still corresponds to c. $240000$ photons per second, or $1500$ photons per bit. If we assume $f=2.3{\rm GHz}$ this becomes $415$ photons per bit. And if we introduce some realistic losses here and there perhaps only half of that.
C) (Although not asked in the question) how many photons per bit are needed? The [Shannon limit] $ C=B \, \log_2(1+{\large\frac{S}{N}})$, relates bandwidth $B$, and $S/N$ ratio to maximum channel capacity. It follows that with only thermal noise $N=k\, T_{\rm noise}\,B$, the required energy per bit is:
$$ E_{\rm bit} = \frac S C = k\, T_{\rm noise} \ \frac{2^{\,C/B}-1}{C/B}
\ \Rightarrow \  \lim_{C\ll B}\ E_{\rm bit} = k\, T_{\rm noise} \log 2, 
$$
where $C\ll B$ is the so-called "ultimate" Shannon limit. With only the CMB $(T_{\rm noise}\!=\!3{\rm K})$ we would then need $41 {\rm yJ}$, or $41 \cdot 10^{-24}\,{\rm J}$, per bit.
That's only $7.5$ photons at $8.3 {\rm GHz}$. But additional atmospheric noise and circuit noise, even with a good cryogenic receiver, could easily raise $T_{\rm noise}$ to about $10{\rm K}$ and then we need $25$ photons per bit at $8.3 {\rm GHz}$, and even $91$ at $2.3 {\rm GHz}$. So clearly there is not much margin.

Wow, beside the excellent answer, I have also learnt that the Voyager signal is received on the Earth. I thought it is received by a network of receivers in the space.

@peterh: We can build better antennas on the ground than we can possibly launch due to being not size constrained.

@Joshua Yes but the atmosphere is a sea of quadrillions of photons, how do you find the 400 representing a bit?

@peterh because almost all of the photons in the atmosphere are the wrong frequency or coming from the wrong direction.  The thermal noise Jos discusses at the end of the answer is the 'random' photons from the environment that are absorbed by the antenna.  Deep space probes operate in parts of the spectrum no one else is allowed to radiate in to avoid manmade noise.

On "bad weather days" the atmosphere can of course add more thermal noise than the value I used in the example. Also the cryogenic LNA's can be somewhat worse. The total result can then easily be a factor 2 or 3 more pessimistic, see the complicated bookkeeping discussion around page 55 in : https://descanso.jpl.nasa.gov/monograph/series10/02_Reid_chapt2.pdf

Nice answer! And computing the minimal number of photons needed is really cool. Just a small question: at 2.3GHZ should it be  ~ 5480 photons, not 415, because the 2.3GHZ photons are less energetic, so there are more of them for the same power output?

@François Lagunas The photons are less energetic, but you get quadratically less power because Voyagers beamforming is worse, the transmit antenna gain factor $(\pi d/\lambda)^2$ is lower. The net result is less received photons at lower $f$.

@peterh A reason they might not be relaying is it wouldn't help so much when one leg is disproportionately large. Relaying the signal via Jupiter would mean that instead of a 10s-of-billions-of-kilometers hop (Voyager->Earth), you'd do a 10s-of-billions-of-kilometers hop (Voyager->Jupiter) plus a 100s-of-millions-kilometer hop (Jupiter->Earth). The hard part is still there.

How is this affected by the fact the Voyager radio emission is closer to a coherent state rather than a Fock state with well-defined number of photons? I expect your method to give result close to expected average of photons per second, but hypothetical photon detections should have some Poissonian statistics, thus sometimes more than 415, sometimes less than 415 photons/s, with std. deviation 20.

@Ján Lalinský You are right, for small numbers the spread can be significant and we can obviously only talk about average numbers (also for the thermal noise which is definitely not coherent.) More fundamentally, going to lower noise temperature and/or higher $f$, the number of photons required per bit would fall below $1$ if we just use Shannon, but that will not happen with a more advanced description based on QM (barring superdense coding, which is of course not used here!)

I assume the decreasing rate of signal strength could be calculated by calculating the derivative of the equation B over D?

@JosBergervoet do you know of a source giving such claims about number of photons per bit?

This answer might be nuanced by the fact that voyager uses Solomon Reed erasure encoding to encode a small number of bits issuing hundreds of bits, so that the photons per "real bit" are magnified and a signal can be received even if its perceived power is below the noise floor.

FYI this post has been screenshotted and posted on Twitter, without attribution.     https://x.com/Duderichy/status/1797633261625393225

If my memory serves me correctly, the Voyager dishes are made from carbon fibre reinforced plastic (CFRP), and in an attempt to save weight, they were not metallised. That reduces the efficiency of the dish surfaces to around 25%, depending on the relative permittivity of the CFRP, so the margin is perhaps 3-5 dB less than the calculations suggest.
Engineering traffic is sent at 40 bits/sec, so it has a higher margin and could outlast the 160 bits/sec science stream if the RTG power doesn't give out first.

Also the "aperture efficiency" gives probably at least 3dB extra loss. (For both Tx and Rx dish, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_antenna#Gain ). And other things could be worse than assumed. This makes sense, because clearly we would not spend time on our biggest radio telescopes if there was enough margin to do it with smaller ones!
